# R (4.1.3) crashes when trying to open the 64 bit version

Tags: r, rstudio

When I try to open R in the most current version (4.1.3) in 64-bit (Rgui.exe), the application closes as soon as it opens.

I believe this is the reason why RStudio doesn't work on my machine (I have a Windows 10 64bit machine).

RStudio only works if I use version 4.0.3 of R, which unfortunately doesn't run some libraries I need

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What version of RStudio are you running? Do you have an `.Rprofile` in your home directory to auto run code when R starts? See the `?Startup` help page info here: https://rdrr.io/r/base/Startup.html for other possible scripts that might autorun that could cause a problem.

Comment: i am using the lastest RStudio version. I am not using any .rprofile, its my first instalation of RStudio in this computer

Comment: Well, If R itself won't run, then there's nothing RStudio can do -- RStudio is just an IDE. I've never heard of R itself crashing on open on Windows after a fresh install. There must something odd about your system configuration. I assume you installed R directly from CRAN? https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/. Its going to be difficult to help much further without specific details for us to reproduce the issue.